# NgZone nor ApplicationRef are injected into Angular component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have two components, `A` and `B`. The component `B` is a child of `A`. I pass a function from `A` to `B` to access and update some properties of `A` in `B`. When I do so, Angular does not rerender (it will rerender if I call the same function from `A`).

To solve the issue, I am injecting `NgZone` to do the update inside its `run`, but it won't get injected. I tried the same with `ApplicationRef` and `ChangeDetectorRef`, but none of them are injected (I get `Cannot read property 'run' of undefined`).

A.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-A',
  templateUrl: './A.component.html',
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  someList: BModel[];

  constructor(
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private fooClient: FooService,
    private barService: barService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  setFlag(enabled: boolean) {
    console.log(`flag was set to ${enabled}`);
    this.flag = enabled;
    this.ngZone.run(() => this.flag = enabled);
  }
}
```

A.component.html

```
<app-B [setFlag]="setFlag"></app-B>
```

B.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-B',
  templateUrl: './B.component.html',
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() setFlag: (_: boolean) => void;

  constructor(private fooClient: FooService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  submit() {
    this.setFlag(false);
  }
}
```

I see in the logs that the function is being called, but Angular won't rerender, and `ngZone` is `undefined`. Using annotator `@Inject(NgZone)` or switching between JiT/AoT or dev/prod didn't solve the issue.

Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/change-case": "^2.3.1",
    "capital-case": "^1.0.3",
    "change-case": "^4.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.25",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.6",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use [@Output()](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) and [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) to communicate between child and parent component. With that you can leave the change detection, and ngZone. There's a [tutorial](https://angular.io/start#output) in the guides.

A component class:

```
export class AComponent {
  onSetFlag(enabled: boolean) {
    console.log(`flag was set to ${enabled}`);
    this.flag = enabled;
  }
}
```

A component template:

```
<app-b (setFlag)="onSetFlag(flag)"></app-b>
```

B component class:

```
export class BComponent {
  @Output() setFlag= new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  onSubmit(){
    setFlag.next(true);
  }
}
```